# Get last item from a table using Selenium Driver C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2012

I am new working with selenium driver and C# and I am facing few problems.

I have a table created by an asp.net webforms application. I can't change this software and I need to take the last link from this table.

This is the table code generated by the asp.net webforms application.

```html
<div class="table table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder_grdResults" style="border-collapse:collapse;" border="1" rules="all" cellspacing="0">
 
 <tbody>
  <tr align="right" class="text-bold bg-gray">
   <td colspan="3"><span>1</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="text-bold bg-gray">
   <td style="width:32px;"> 
   </td>
   <td>
    Description
   </td>
   <td>
    Expired?
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
                         <input name="chkView213311910" class="check" id="chkView213311910" style="border-style: none;" type="checkbox" value="213311910" /> 
                        </td>
   <td>
                         <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
       </td>
       <td title="Expired" style="width: 20px; border-right: 1px solid #B3B3B3;   margin-right: 15px;    display:  inline-block;    padding-right: 25px;">
       </td>
       <td style="width: 25px; border-right: 1px solid #B3B3B3;   margin-right: 15px;    display:  inline-block;    padding-right: 25px;">
        <a href="ShowObjectFile.aspx?ObjectID=213311910" target="_blank">
         <i class="fa fa-lg fa-file-pdf-o" hspace="4" alt="File type PDF">
         </i>
        </a>
       </td>
       <td>
        <font color="dimgray">
         <a href="ViewObject.aspx?ObjectID=213311910">
          First Link
         </a>
        </font>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
                        </td>
   <td>
                         <span id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder_grdResults__ctl3_lblCheckedOut">Não</span>
                        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
                         <input name="chkView213312924" class="check" id="chkView213312924" style="border-style: none;" type="checkbox" value="213312924" /> 
                        </td><td>
                         <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
       </td>
       <td style="width: 20px; border-right: 1px solid #B3B3B3;   margin-right: 15px;    display:  inline-block;    padding-right: 25px;">
       </td>
       <td style="width: 25px; border-right: 1px solid #B3B3B3;   margin-right: 15px;    display:  inline-block;    padding-right: 25px;">
        <a href="ShowObjectFile.aspx?ObjectID=213312924" target="_blank">
         <i class="fa fa-lg fa-file-pdf-o" hspace="4" alt="file Type pdf">
         </i>
        </a>
       </td>
       <td>
        <font color="dimgray">
         <a href="ViewObject.aspx?ObjectID=213312924">
          Second Link
         </a>
        </font>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    </td><td>
```

Besides click on the last link (Second link), I 
Also I need to save the **ViewObject.aspx?ObjectID=213312924** (this is where I will go when I click on the link) on a variable.

Can someone please, help me with this issue?

Comment: You want to get the `Second Link` url?, is that what you want?

Comment: do you mean last link, regardless what it is, or does it always come with some known text, e.g. `Second Link`

Comment: @Hackerman first I need to store the url text on a variable. Then I need to click on this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all the links in a `List` of `IWebElements` and then pick the last one. Something like this:

```
IWebElement el = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""));
IList<IWebElement> allLinks = el.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
IWebElement linkYouNeed = allLinks[allLinks.Count- 1];
```